# Enlarge image on mouseover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple image link button that when I move my mouse on it, it gets a bit larger.
I managed to do it with this simple code below but now I just want to move also the paragraph when the image is getting larger..

Any hints on how I can select and move the paragraph when I hover over the image?

```
<div id="rightImage">
      <a href="http://blabla.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image" onmouseover="this.className='mouseOver'" onmouseout="this.className='mouseOut'" /></a>
      <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>


#rightImage
{
    width:275px;
    height:275px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.mouseOver
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    top:-40px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:2px -2px 10px 3px #888, inset 2px -2px 10px 3px #888;
}

.mouseOut
{ 
    width:275px;
    height:275px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:52px;
    box-shadow:2px -2px 10px 3px #888, inset 2px -2px 10px 3px #888;
 }
```

Comment: for mouseover and mouseout there is a property in css element:hover...why r u not using that???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This enlarges the image, increases the size of the shadow and keeps the <p> element visible.

(EDIT: I forgot to encode the angled braces around the p)

Perhaps it's what you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
<style>
#rightImage
{
    height:275px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow:2px -2px 10px 3px #888, inset 2px -2px 10px 3px #888;
}
#rightImage:hover img
{
    height: 300px;
    box-shadow:4px -4px 10px 3px #888, inset 4px -4px 10px 3px #888;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rightImage">
        <a href="http://blabla.com" target="_blank"> <img src="img/redBaron.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position:absolute`

```
.mouseOver
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;   
    z-index:1;    
    box-shadow:2px -2px 10px 3px #888, inset 2px -2px 10px 3px #888;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/aRv2M/2/

Comment: Sowmya thanks for your quick response, but i dont want the image to enlarge only on the two dimensions. I need to have it position:absolute. Any other ideas?:}

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  I hope it works for you.

```
<div id="rightImage">
  <a href="http://blabla.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image" width="275px" height="275" /></a>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

> use this css

```
#rightImage{
width:275px;
height:275px;
float:left;
position:relative;}

#rightImage:hover{
width:300px;
height:300px;
top:-40px
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
box-shadow:2px -2px 10px 3px #888, inset 2px -2px 10px 3px #888;}

#rightImage:hover p {
position:relative;
margin-top:30px;}​
```